# Ubuntu 12.04+Eclipse Juno not showing options

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new using Eclipse (I just started with Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu 12.04 64bits) and I'm having a weird problem. Thing is, when I open a New Android Aplication Project, in the configure launcher icon window there is a missing bar to adjust the additional padding. Any clue why is that? My biggest worry is If I'm loosing anything else and I don't know because I'm new using that IDE. I add an image that explains It better.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/androidg.png/

thanks

Comment: I checked mine, also on ubuntu 12.04 x64 and have the same bug.  I know that this did not happen prior to update in ADT 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395. Will keep trying to find out.  But this is a minor thing, you can make your launcher icon with the padding you want in your favorite image editor; or let a pro do it :).
Also, Im on eclipse 3.7 ; so maybe it is not related to eclipse

Comment: Found this alternative, or, the same thing webbased: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.005&foreground.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Fsocial_group.svg&foreColor=9c0%2C0&crop=1&backgroundShape=circle&backColor=ffffff%2C100

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for answer. I hope this is the only thing that is missing.